# Predictive Modeling 3 Variables: A Correlation-Based Approach

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, correlation, prediction

I have 3 fields in a complete data set, Store Count, Orders and Population. Using these details I was able to create a correlation matrix (see table below), using the Correl() function in google sheets.

[image]

In another dataset that is not complete, I want to calculate **Orders**, where I have Population Data and Store Count data. Based on the correlation matrix

This is not something I have tried to do before, so any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If this is not the right approach, please let me know